# Как переместить и запустить рабочий проект Laravel на другом ПК

Tags: php, laravel

я новичок в Laravel. Хочу перенести проект с ноутбука на ПК. 
Вот что я сделал:

1. Скопировал проект в domains.
2. Установил Composer
3. Загрузил установщик Laravel.
4. artisan key:generate
5. artisan cache:clear
6. artisan migrate

в итоге через artisan serve работает, но не запускается с OpenServer. Выдает ошибку в браузере "Не удается получить доступ к сайту. Не удалось найти IP-адрес сервера laravelu.loc". 
Содержимое файла .htaccess который сам добавил в проект:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Будьте добры

Answer (score 0):

В опенсервере есть такая настройка(ПКМ по значку Опенсервера -> настройки -> Алиасы) как "Алисы" вот туда вам надо имя домена и путь к папке `myawesomesite.loc/public`

Comment: Я попробовал через Домены (ПКМ по значку Опенсервера -> настройки -> Домены). не работает, хотя тот же проект работает с таким методом на компе где создан проект.  Мне бы хотелось проект запускался именно через .htaccess

Comment: @Swartex - алиасы или домены? Это разные вещи

Comment: @Жаздеми, ваша ошибка говорит "что то не так с опенсервером". Файл .htacess - это, грубо говоря, набор конфиг. параметров для апача - вы понимаете, что делают эти настройки?

Answer (score 0):

За акцент извините не русский,
надо делать так копировать Все файли в те папки который нужно
в файле .env написать базу данных, узера паролья хост нейма
потом сделать php artisan migrate

Comment: За акцент не извиняйтесь )) Я тоже не русский. Проект перенес. Работает как надо. Спасибо за отклик.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать git. Проект будет лежать там и вы сможете быстро и без заморочек скачать проект. Если вы используете phpStorm или VSCode то там всё очень удобно. Использование git репозиториев правильнее чем способ который вы используете.
Ссылка на инструкцию использования без phpStorm или VSCode:

```
https://arcadepub.ru/2021/05/06/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-laravel-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-4-git/
```

Ссылка на использование с phpStorm:

```
https://zhurov.me/blog/phpstorm-almost-all-you-wanna-know-about-git.html
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/871444)